# Complex forms with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need the form that will edit the array of entities and their related entities(one to many).
Like this:
Person has many Orders. Form for array of People with their orders.

What rails API can be used to build this form?
Please give a code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following tutorials:

1. [Edit Multiple Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple)
2. [Nested Object Form](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out nested_attributes_for in Rails 2.3

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes